# Chrome API: how to use the current empty "New Tab" instead of creating another one?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Suppose you have just opened Chrome. There is a "New Tab" already open. My extension has a button that when the user presses it, I create a new tab to show my contents (index.html).

Now everything works fine, but the problem is that "New Tab" is left useless. I use the following call to create a new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
  "url":"index.html"
});
```

update() doesn't work (nothing happens).

```
chrome.tabs.update({
  "url":"index.html"
});
```

When I check the current tab, it says "undefined":

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(t){console.log(t.id)})
```

How can I use the current empty tab instead of creating a new one? I see some other extensions (namely [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff)) have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the Tabs API does not allow you to omit leading optional argunemts like, e.g., jQuery does.  To change the current tab, you need to explictly include `null` as the first argument (tabId) to `update()`:

```
chrome.tabs.update(null, {
    "url":"index.html"
});
```

Comment: that's interesting. I'll try it as soon as I can and will come back with feedback.